# webpack includes the whole library instead of only a part of it

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a simple component and I am trying to use webpack for my build process, so I have something like

```
import React      from 'react';
import { AppBar } from 'material-ui';

export default () => (
  <AppBar
    title="Octopus"
    showMenuIconButton={ false }
    iconElementRight={<SaveLoadAnimation/>}
  />
);
```

I am using the external `AppBar` component. And in my build process I exclude React from the bundle like this:

```
externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react'
    }
}
```

The problems is that Webpack includes in the build the whole `material-ui` library instead of only the `AppBar` component. Is it a way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing from the main file of material-ui which exports all components.

See:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/index.js

You could try target a component directly.  For example

```
import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';
```

That could *possibly* work, but I haven't tried.

Webpack version 2 has a cool new feature called tree shaking.  This allows bundles to automatically shake off any excess code which isn't used.  This could be another alternative if the above approach doesn't work.

Here is an example app making use of Webpack 2 and it's tree shaking feature:
https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2

---

**Update**

There is a thread on material-ui that discusses better imports and tree shaking.
See: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2679

Comment: I dont see any difference by using `import .. from 'material-ui/AppBar-ui', unless there is any option in webpack that I have to configure?

Comment: Try `import AppBar from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar';`

Comment: sorry, typo, this is exactly what I have `import AppBar     from 'material-ui/lib/app-bar'`... no tree-shaking, the full library is imported

Comment: Ah sorry it didn't work. :(  You may need to follow that thread I posted on the update, and consider a tree shaking approach.

Comment: If you look at the source for the app bar it imports quite a bit of the library, so it's probably a propagation of imports going on.